# Copy and Paste URL parameter on HTML Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one parameter from ExactSales called **%%name%%**.

When I send one email to my subscribers the parameters are replaced by the user name. Let's suppose the user is Paul, in my email will be replaced with this name.

> Example: Hello, **Paul**.

In these emails I have one button, with the URL, this URL is automaticly replaced too, because it has the parameter **%%name%%** too;

> http://www.mysubscribers.com/XX-XX-20181101-XX-XX/**Paul**

This URL opens one landing page with my content.

I need one script that copy the parameter after the last "/" from the URL and paste on my HTML code where I want.

> Example: Hello, **Paul**.

Is there posible?
I don't know to much about javascript, can someone help me with this?

```
var url = window.location.href;
var parameters = url.split('/');
console.log(parameters[parameters.length - 1])
```

or something like

```
var str = "http://www.inversa.com/XV-MI-LJI-GLP-AIN-20181101-ADEA-PSNL-PR3-X/Marcus"; 
var res = str.slice(66);
console.log("Hello," + res);
```

And how Can I copy wherever I want in my HTML?

Hello, **NAME**

Comment: What is wrong with the first code block at the end of your question ? That should do exactly what you want.

Comment: How do I copy the parameter wherever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question you can use this code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- copy last item of a link es.
      http://www.mysubscribers.com/XX-XX-20181101-XX-XX/Paul
      you get Paul
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var url="http://www.mysubscribers.com/XX-XX-20181101-XX-XX/Paul";
      var name=url.split("/").pop(-1);
      document.getElementById('myH1').innerHTML=name;//put into h1 the name
      alert(name);//show alert with name

    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="myH1"></h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I will use differents URLs. I need to get the las parameter after the / and paste on the HTML content.

Comment: sorry but did you try my code snippet? it does that you said...or i am don't understand your question...

Comment: I will use differents URL's and the middle parameter /XX-XX-20181101-XX-XX/ is not the same too. and the name will change according to the user. So the script must take the parameter after the last "/".

Comment: into my code change  var url="http://www.mysubscribers.com/XX-XX-20181101-XX-XX/Paul"; in  var url=window.location.href;  and you get the last item after /

Comment: Working! But it displays one alert too, how can i don't display this alert.

Comment: THANKS ! WORKING ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the link more dynamic, assuming it always ends with a /name.

This code will separate the string in to an array at every slash, then get the last item of the array.

html code:

```
<p>Hello <span id="name"></span></p>
```

JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  getUrl();
});

function getUrl(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  var str = url.split('/');
  var name = str.pop();
  $('#name').html(name);

}
```

Comment: But how do I use on my HTML to call the name?
<p>Hello, <strong>NAME</strong></p>

Comment: Oh I see, well you would have to make a JavaScript call and insert the name in to your HTML. Maybe if you supplied some more code we could supply a more accurate answer?

Comment: The %%name%% is provided by ExactSales, my only script is to get the parameter from the URL. Now I need one to paste the parameter on the text where I want, but I don't have a clue on how to do that.

Comment: In your JavaScript, create a document on load function which gets the URL and then puts the name in to your html.

Comment: Ok, I will search one script who does that :) Thanks

Comment: I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Sir, isn't working;

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(() => {
  getUrl();
});

function getUrl(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  var str = url.split('/');
  var name = str.pop();
  $('#name').html(name);

}
</script>

HTML
 <p>Hello <span id="name"></span></p>